# Premake (v5) with VS2013 and C#: "x64" platforms not being set to 64 bit OR to even build within the solution's configuration manager

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, 64-bit, premake

I'm using premake5 with VS2013 to create a SharedLib in C#. I am running the following at the solution level, before I list my projects:

```
configurations { "Debug", "Release" }
platforms { "Win32", "Win64" }

    filter "configurations:Debug"
        defines { "DEBUG" }
        flags { "Symbols" }

    filter "configurations:Release"
        defines { "NDEBUG" }
        optimize "On"

    filter "platforms:Win32"
        system "Windows"
        architecture "x32"

    filter "platforms:Win64"
        system "Windows"
        architecture "x64"
```

This generates a solution file as well as project files. However, upon opening the solution in VS2013 and setting the build platform to Win64, I notice that it does not build. After checking the configuration manager, I notice that my projects are set to x86 for both Win32 and Win64. They are also not even set to build for either the Release or Debug Win64 build. They are, however, set to build in either of the Win32s. I would love to post screenshots, but my reputation is too low.

It really seems like i'm just not setting it to 64 bit correctly. Is "x64" the correct string to use? Is there just a bug with premake? I should note that I can manually set Win64 to x64 and check the "build" box within the configuration manager after opening the solution.

Edit:
I confirmed that the problem is within the generation of the solution file. The GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution entries are being written as the following:

```
GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {25F339C1-1195-6497-FA4F-78EBE690EBE7}.Debug|Win64.ActiveCfg = Debug Win64|x64
        {25F339C1-1195-6497-FA4F-78EBE690EBE7}.Debug|Win64.Build.0 = Debug Win64|x64
        {25F339C1-1195-6497-FA4F-78EBE690EBE7}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86
        {25F339C1-1195-6497-FA4F-78EBE690EBE7}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|x86
        {25F339C1-1195-6497-FA4F-78EBE690EBE7}.Release|Win64.ActiveCfg = Release Win64|x64
        {25F339C1-1195-6497-FA4F-78EBE690EBE7}.Release|Win64.Build.0 = Release Win64|x64
        {25F339C1-1195-6497-FA4F-78EBE690EBE7}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|x86
        {25F339C1-1195-6497-FA4F-78EBE690EBE7}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|x86
        {01747461-6D34-F097-366F-3915A2EE3474}.Debug|Win64.ActiveCfg = Debug Win64|x64
        {01747461-6D34-F097-366F-3915A2EE3474}.Debug|Win64.Build.0 = Debug Win64|x64
        {01747461-6D34-F097-366F-3915A2EE3474}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86
        {01747461-6D34-F097-366F-3915A2EE3474}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|x86
        {01747461-6D34-F097-366F-3915A2EE3474}.Release|Win64.ActiveCfg = Release Win64|x64
        {01747461-6D34-F097-366F-3915A2EE3474}.Release|Win64.Build.0 = Release Win64|x64
        {01747461-6D34-F097-366F-3915A2EE3474}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|x86
        {01747461-6D34-F097-366F-3915A2EE3474}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|x86
    EndGlobalSection
```

When they SHOULD be written as:

```
GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {25F339C1-1195-6497-FA4F-78EBE690EBE7}.Debug|Win64.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {25F339C1-1195-6497-FA4F-78EBE690EBE7}.Debug|Win64.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {25F339C1-1195-6497-FA4F-78EBE690EBE7}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86
        {25F339C1-1195-6497-FA4F-78EBE690EBE7}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|x86
        {25F339C1-1195-6497-FA4F-78EBE690EBE7}.Release|Win64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
        {25F339C1-1195-6497-FA4F-78EBE690EBE7}.Release|Win64.Build.0 = Release|x64
        {25F339C1-1195-6497-FA4F-78EBE690EBE7}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|x86
        {25F339C1-1195-6497-FA4F-78EBE690EBE7}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|x86
        {01747461-6D34-F097-366F-3915A2EE3474}.Debug|Win64.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {01747461-6D34-F097-366F-3915A2EE3474}.Debug|Win64.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {01747461-6D34-F097-366F-3915A2EE3474}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86
        {01747461-6D34-F097-366F-3915A2EE3474}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|x86
        {01747461-6D34-F097-366F-3915A2EE3474}.Release|Win64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
        {01747461-6D34-F097-366F-3915A2EE3474}.Release|Win64.Build.0 = Release|x64
        {01747461-6D34-F097-366F-3915A2EE3474}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|x86
        {01747461-6D34-F097-366F-3915A2EE3474}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|x86
    EndGlobalSection
```

Comment: Typically the strings are "AnyCPU", "x86" and "x64", not "x32". The platforms are named the same as the architecture. Check the Properties->Build tab of one of your projects in VS to see what is used. These of course can be changed from the build configurations dialog if you want.

Comment: I checked it out and added more information to my question. Also, premake5 doesn't seem to mind if I use "x32" or "x86".

Comment: I can reproduce this issue and am investigating.

Answer (score 1):

So, I ran into this as well, setting up a simple x86/64 project.  I found this worked:

```
-- premake5.lua
workspace "Sample"
  configurations { "Debug", "Release" }
  platforms { "x86", "x86_64" }
  location "build"

project "Sample01"
  kind "ConsoleApp"
  language "C++"
  location "build/sample01"
  targetdir "bin/%{cfg.buildcfg}"

  files { "%{prj.name}/src/**.h", "%{prj.name}/src/**.cpp" }

  filter "configurations:Debug"
    defines { "DEBUG" }
    flags { "Symbols" }

  filter "configurations:Release"
    defines { "NDEBUG" }
    optimize "On"

    filter "platforms:x86"
        system "Windows"
        architecture "x86"

    filter "platforms:x86_64"
        system "Windows"
        architecture "x86_64"
```

I know the topic is kind of old, but this may save someone some grief later on.

My project structure looks like this, btw:

```
- sample [folder]
  - sample01 [folder]
    - src [folder]
       main.cpp
  premake5.lua
```

This generates a VS 2013 project and compiles without error.  I've also shared this in github: https://github.com/Nuclearfossil/sample

Answer (score 1):

You've found a bug! I've [submitted a pull request](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/pull/218) to the project to fix it. In the meantime, as described here, you can work around the problem by renaming your "Win64" platform to "x86_64".

This fix should land in the Premake 5.0-alpha6 release.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by making the following change to vs2005_solution.lua at line 222 (and running 'premake5 embed' and rebuilding the solution):

```
--Change by Kpick, at least for vs2013, the format is different
if _ACTION < "vs2013" then
    _p(2,'{%s}.%s.ActiveCfg = %s|%s', prj.uuid, descriptor, platform, architecture)
else
    _p(2,'{%s}.%s.ActiveCfg = %s|%s', prj.uuid, descriptor, cfg.buildcfg, architecture)
end

-- Only output Build.0 entries for buildable configurations

if not excluded and prjCfg.kind ~= premake.NONE then
    --Change by Kpick, at least for vs2013, the format is different
    if _ACTION < "vs2013" then
        _p(2,'{%s}.%s.Build.0 = %s|%s', prj.uuid, descriptor, platform, architecture)
    else
        _p(2,'{%s}.%s.Build.0 = %s|%s', prj.uuid, descriptor, cfg.buildcfg, architecture)
    end
end
```

I should note that I haven't verified that this change is needed ONLY for vs2013, but  didn't want to modify the source code any more than I had to.